# How to remove margin in material-tab of AngularDart material comonents

Tags: dart, angular-dart, angular-components, dart-html, dart-webui

I want to remove the margins from **material-tab-components** of ***AngularDart Material Components***. How can I do that?
[image]

tab_component.html

```
<material-tab-panel centerStrip class="tab-panel visible-desktop" [activeTabIndex]="1">
    <material-tab label="Home">
        Eager Content of Tab 1
    </material-tab>
    <material-tab label="Tab 1">
        <div class="tab-background">

        </div>
    </material-tab>
    <material-tab label="Tab 2">
        Eager Content of Tab 3
    </material-tab>
    <material-tab label="Tab 3">
        Eager Content of Tab 3
    </material-tab>
</material-tab-panel>
```

tab_component.scss

```
@import 'package:angular_components/tree/master/lib/css/material/material';
@import 'package:angular_components/tree/master/lib/material_tab/mixins';

@include tab-panel-accent-color('.tab-panel', $mat-red);
@include tab-panel-tab-strip-width('material-tab-panel[centerStrip]', 400px);
```

tab_component.css

```
material-tab-panel {
    width: 400px;
}

material-tab {
    width: 100vw;
}

.tab-background {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: aqua;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The padding is set with the material-tab class. You can change it by overwriting it in your tab_component.css like so:

```
material-tab.material-tab {
  padding: 0px;
}
```